# Microkernel (e.g. GNU Hurd) more secure than monolithic kernel (Linux)?

Tags: kernel, security, linux-kernel, hurd

I would like to understand (in relatively layman's terms) if and how a microkernel such as the [Mach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_%28kernel%29)-based [GNU Hurd](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd.html) is more secure than a monolithic kernel such a [Linux](http://www.kernel.org/).

Additionally, does a micro-kernel affect network security differently form a monolithic kernel?